# How can I load and query RDF at the same time

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, semantic-web, sesame

Can you think of any way to load and query RDF triples at the same time?

I just know that in Sesame  you have to first initialize a repository (like loading rdf file) and then you are able to query through SPARQL.

Imagine we initialize an RDF repository(input a file) and do not want for loading to be finished, but at the same time of loading RDF data, want to query data through SPARQL for validation purposes.

For the below initialization, one should wait until the loading of RDF file in repository is finished (my assumption), just then you can query RDF data in repository:

```java
File rdfFile; // parameter, RDF file.
repo = new SailRepository(new MemoryStore());
repo.initialize();

        try {
            RepositoryConnection con = repo.getConnection();
            try {
                con.add(rdfFile, null, rdfFormat);
            } finally {
                con.close();
            }
        }
```

In the above code, `RepositoryConnection.add` gets a `File` as argument. Would giving a `FileInputStream` as parameter resolve the problem? (Initialization of repository does not wait for loading the file and it will be possible to query before loading is finished).

Comment: Asking for tool recommendations is off topic on SO. Try describing the problem instead (example code) and what you have tried sofar to solve it.

Comment: Also: what do you mean with "load and query at the same time", exactly? I'm pretty sure that if you wanted to you could setup a Sesame Repository, load data into it, and then query it in about 3-6 lines of code - and if you somehow wanted to simplify that, you could very easily write a quick utility method yourself. So it's not very clear what you're looking for, either.

Comment: Hello, I edited the post.

Comment: I will make the text clear, SORRY. The problem is do not wait for loading RDF in the repository and being able to query before the RDF file is completely loaded.

Comment: Much clearer like this, thanks

Comment: You could use multithreading to perform tasks simultaneously. IMO - I can't see a useful use case for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `FileInputStream` instead of a `File` won't make a difference in how Sesame processes the file: the `add` method will still not return until it has completely added the data.

However, you can achieve what you want by executing the query in a separate thread from the loading of the file, and then using a transaction with isolation level `READ_UNCOMMITTED`. Of course, there are few guarantees of completeness or consistency of the query result in such a scenario, but it's technically possible.

Something like this (from the top of my head, so untested):

```java
   File rdfFile; // parameter, RDF file.
   repo = new SailRepository(new MemoryStore());
   repo.initialize();

   Thead loader = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
       try (RepositoryConnection con = repo.getConnection()) {
            con.add(rdfFile, null, rdfFormat);
       }
      }
   };
   Thead query = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
       try (RepositoryConnection con = repo.getConnection()) {
        conn.begin(IsolationLevels.READ_UNCOMMITTED);
        String query = "SELECT * WHERE ... "; 
        try(TupleQueryResult result = conn.prepareTupleQuery(query).evaluate()) {
           while (result.hasNext()) {
                ...
           }
        }
        conn.commit();
      }
   };
   loader.start(); 
   query.start();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What about the parameter of add method? doesnt it make any difference to use FileInputStream instead of File?

Comment: @javadeveloper that doesn't make a difference. I've updated the answer to explain this.

Comment: Yes of course, give me a bit time please. Thanks ;)